# File 'picins.sty' not found

Tags: errors, miktex, texmaker

Even installing the wrapfig package for this error. I use miktex + texmaker.
can anybody help me?

Comment: It seems like you have to download it manually from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins). ([Direct link to sty file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/picins.sty)) This appears to be caused by the fact that no appropriate license has been chosen by the author of the package.

Comment: if you install `wrapfig` then you can use `\usepackage{wrapfig}`  `picins` an old and unsupported package that is not in texlive, as noted in the comment above you can get it from ctan if you really need it. Note that is is in the area for latex2.09 that is latex from before 1993, are you sure you want that in a document this century?

Comment: How can I install this picins?

Comment: @DiegoRangel As already pointed out: Download [the sty file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/picins.sty), put it into the same directory as your document where you are including it (in the simplest case) and it should work. (You may consider putting it into a local `texmf` tree or use the newer `wrapfig` package mentioned by @DavidCarlisle.)

Comment: @davidcarlisle millenium, even! :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/picins?lang=en